# Unable to display category name of post

Tags: php, wordpress

On my home page, I'm trying to loop through a set number of posts and display the category name of each post. The category that I'm trying to display the name for is a subcategory of a parent (if that makes any difference). Here's my code for it:

```
        <?php 
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => '15' );
            $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args ); 
            foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
                $category = get_the_category($recent['ID']);
                echo $category['cat-name'];
        }; ?>
```

When I run that, nothing ends up displaying. That page displays as if the code wasn't there. But when I do a var_dump on $category:

```
        <?php 
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => '15' );
            $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args ); 
            foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
                $category = get_the_category($recent['ID']);
                echo var_dump($category);
        }; ?>
```

I can see that everything is there that I need. Each post, with it's keys and values, but for some reason trying to display a specific property of a post (like 'cat-name', or even 'name') doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) will return an array of WP_Term objects, one for each category assigned to the post.

This means you need to loop through the array, or if you only have 1 array in there fetch it using

```
$category[0]->name;
```

Comment: I tried, but apparently my newbie-ness prevents it from incrementing the count...lame.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php get_cat_name( $cat_id ) ?>
```

Example

```
<?php echo get_cat_name(4);?>
```

if you want to know more about category name display or other about category in wordpress you can visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name